# Detect user interaction with a view using UIGestureDetector

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, calendarkit

I need to determine if the user is holding his finger on the view or has released it. Ideally, I need an `UIGestureRecognizer` that will register touch start and end events, but without preventing subviews from handling user gestures.

It important to say that inheriting from any view and overriding the `touchesBegan(touches:with:)` and `touchesEnded(touches:with:)` methods won't help - the view I'm working with is final (`DayView` from [CalendarKit](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)). Overriding these methods in ViewController will not help either because they do won't called when user interacting with controller's subviews.

How can I make it so that `UIGestureRecognizer` does not interfere with touch events?

Comment: Please, submit a PR with removing `final` modifier for the `DayView`. using `touchesBegan` is a good direction.

Comment: @RichardTopchii This will not solve the problem. Touch-methods of the DayView will not be called when switching pages in TimelinePagerView or scrolling in TimelineContainer.